# How to solve AAPt 2 error in android studio?

Tags: android

Java Compiler Error: "Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details"

Comment: did you check the logs?

Comment: @mark_keen where to find that?